# Error with http request to PHP fiile angular

Tags: php, angularjs, http

I am trying to make a http request to my php file. But it returns me the following error

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"localhost/sample.php","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}

My angular request is

```
var some = angular.module("first_module", [])
            .controller("first_controller", function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $http.get('localhost/sample.php').then(function(response) {
                    $scope.students = response;
                    $log.info();
        });
});
```

My PHP file is

```
<?php
$var2 = new stdClass();
$var2->name = 'john';
$var2->class = '7';
$var2->fee = '45000';
$var2->point = '5';
$response[0] = $var2;
$var2->name = 'ahmed';
$var2->class = '7';
$var2->fee = '55600';
$var2->point = '2';
$response[1] = $var2;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I am unable to understand the error even. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
on adding an another function for failure and print the log in console I receive the following error

```
var some = angular.module("first_module", [])
            .controller("first_controller", function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $http.get('localhost/sample.php').then(function(response) {
                    $scope.students = response;
                    $log.info();
        }, function(err) {
                      console.log($log.info);
         });
});
```

This is the error I receive [image]

Comment: I havent worked with php calls but i think you should remove `localhost` from $http. Can you share the console error screen shot

Comment: Thanks for reply but I receive the same error on removing localhost even

Comment: Share the screen shot of console error.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank Vivek for reply and updated it with an image

Comment: Can you manually open sample.php in a new tab and update the question with the content

Comment: A status of -1 often indicates a CORS problem.

Comment: @ Devansh J thanks for the reply. when I open it manually in a page it is printing the json data successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take an safer approach:

Take your URL an test it in Browser,

```
Http(s)://localhost/sample.php
```

if the Browser returns your result and everything is fine then use the full URL in your code. (With this test you are testing that your server is running, and the .php file returns the expected values as json.)

```
$http.get('http://localhost/sample.php')
```

Or if you are sure on which relative path your files are. Like executing all files in same folder.

```
$http.get('sample.php')
```

Comment: My sample.php is on apache server on ubuntu system i.e in directory /var/www/html/ but my angular file is in Desktop. I can't find any reason for the error ? However thanks for answer. And the url http://localhost/sample.php is printing the json data perfectly.

Comment: You need to run angular also on the Server. You can get domain-cross-script errors. Try to put your angular app in a subfolder .../html/app and then go with localhost/app/angular.html